# Dart: How to json decode '0' as double

Tags: dart

I have a service that is sending me a list of values and after parsing with the 'dart:convert json.decode' I get a List < dynamic >  json as such:

```
(values) [ 0.23, 0.2, 0, 0.43 ]
```

When I try to parse the values to 'double', I get a parsing error

```
double value = values[2] // error
```

Because if we check the .runtimeType of each element we can see that we have the following

```
[double, double, int, double]
```

So, how can I avoid '0' being interpreted as int?
I would like to avoid using a function like this:

```
double jsonToDouble(dynamic value) {
  if(value.runtimeType == int) {
    return (value as int).toDouble();
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: did you try to map the values array ?
`values .map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();`

Comment: I will update my question because I start with a 'List<dynamic> values' that is the list that I mention and if I do a mapping like you mention I will end up with a 'List' and not a 'List<double>' that I need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add some special logic to the JSON decoding by constructing your own codec with a reviver. This callback will be invoked for every property in a map or item in a List.

```
  final myJsonCodec = new JsonCodec.withReviver((dynamic key, dynamic value) {
     if (value is int) return value.toDouble();
     return value;
  });
```

However, you will *always* get a `List<dynamic>` from `dart:covert`, whether or not all of your number types are doubles or ints.  Depending on what version of dart you are on you *may* be able to use `List.cast` to convert to a `List<double>`.

```
List<double> values = oldValues.cast<double>();
```

If that isn't available, you can create a new `List<double>` and add your values to it so that the runtime type is correctly set.

Answer (score 4):

Doubles have a `toDouble()` method. So, you can use that in both cases (`double` and `int`).

```
double jsonToDouble(dynamic value) {
   return value.toDouble();
}
```

This works *only* if the value is a `double` or an `int`, though. If the value is a `string`, an exception occurs.